# Ethernet does not work Ubuntu 18.04 - msi B450 tomahawk motherboard

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, msi

I bought a new PC and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it. WI-Fi works okay but I want Ethernet and it does not work. The motherboard with integrated eth is a MSI B450 tomahawk.

Here's the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:17:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 4c:ed:fb:b7:df:31
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.93 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:29 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7500000-f7503fff
```

Ethernet interface is not even listed.

`uname -a`:

`Linux ummon 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:45:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
dkms status
nvidia, 390.77, 4.15.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.77, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108, 4.15.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I don't know what to do as MSI does not list Linux-specific drivers on its website. Should I manually activate the Ethernet interface somehow ?

Comment: Check your BIOS to make sure your ethernet interface is enabled. If so, try booting to a Ubuntu Live 18.10 DVD/USB, as it supports newer hardware, and see if that works. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema thank you, it worked without upgrading to 18.10 - some option was disabled for LAN.

Comment: What option change fixed it for you?